# How to see the error as a function of iteration steps in eigs()

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue

I am using `[Evec,Eval]=eigs(H,1,’sa’)` in Matlab to compute the smallest eigenvalue of a sparse matrix H. Can I get the error of the smallest eigenvalue as a function of iteration step?

Comment: The error? what error?

Comment: Error means the convergence of \Delta Eval  as the iteration step increases?

Comment: But, `Eval` are eigenvalues. Convergence to what? iteration of what? the algorithm inside `eigs`?

Comment: Yes, the algorithm inside eigs.

Comment: You cant. The only option is writing the algorithm yourself.